# Is it possible to limit outgoing emails to one domain?

Tags: email, thunderbird, smtp, google-workspace

A customer of mine has asked if we can set-up their email software at each shop, so that it can only send emails to one domain name.

They are currently using Google Apps with Mozilla Thunderbird 3 installed on each computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Google Apps you can [restrict delivery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542?hl=en).